# Let $f,g : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $\left| g \left(f(x)\right) - g \left(f(y)\right)\right| \lt \left|x-y\right|$, with f not continuous..

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

The problem goes like this:

Let f,g : $\Bbb{R}$ → $\Bbb{R}$ be 2 functions such that:

1. f has the intermediate value property and is not continuous
2. $\left| g \left(f(x)\right) - g \left(f(y)\right)\right| \lt \left|x-y\right|$, for every real numbers $x$,$y$, $x\ne y$.
   Prove that $g$ is not injective.

The first part of the solution, which appears in the book,is the following:

Let $a$ be a point of discontinuity of $f$, therefore there exists $\epsilon\gt 0$ and  a sequence ($x_{n}$) that converges to $a$ , such that f($x_{n}$) - f(a)> $\epsilon$, or f($x_{n}$) - f(a) < $\epsilon$, for every positive integer $n$.

My question is : since the sequence ($x_{n}$) converges to a,it means that f($x_{n}$) converges to f(a), so how is it possible to exist $\epsilon$ such that f($x_{n}$) - f(a)> $\epsilon$ ,for every n?  I mean, from the definition of the limit, if we consider the interval ( f(a); f(a)+$\epsilon$), there should be an infinite number of terms of the sequence ($x_{n}$)...?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rl} x & \mathrm{if}\ x < 0 \\ x-2 & \mathrm{if}\ x \geq 0 \\ \end{array}\right.$. If we choose our sequence of $(x_n)$ converging to $0$ from the right, then we get that the $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(0)$. But if we choose our sequence of $(x_n)$ converging to $0$ from the left, then the $f(x_n)$ converge to $0 \neq f(0) = -2$.